# The dump database on a SSD disk is slowly restored in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, performance, restore, sql-server-2005

I prepared new server for my DB on Windows 2008R2 + SQL Server 2005 SP4.

I always estimated time of restore database of a backup as time of copying of the file of a backup at that place where the base will be located.

But this time this indicator strongly differs.

Copying takes 30 minutes.

Restore database takes 300 minutes.

After restore database all operations work so quickly as expected.

I can't understand in what the reason of such slow restore database.

Comment: You'll need to give more detail than that to get a useful answer: how are you restoring the DB (SSMS, direct SQL `RESTORE DATABASE` statement (in which case provide the statement used), ...)?, is the backup and the destination on the same drive? If not what are the details of the two drives? How are the drives connected (internal, USB, SAN, ...), and so forth.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem by adding couple of paremeter to restore command.

RESTORE DATABASE [test] FROM ...
**MAXTRANSFERSIZE=4194304, BUFFERCOUNT=2048**

I am surprised, it is the first case in my practice when additional parameters so influenced restoration speed.

Comment: I wouldn't be too surprised: the defaults will no doubt be optimised for local spinning metal or "remote" (iSCSI etc) SAN based storage, not local SSDs where the bandwidth and latency issues are quite different. Given the results seen in http://sirsql.net/blog/2011/9/26/optimizing-database-restores.html 2048 might be OTT for the buffer count option.

Answer (score 0):

Basic reason for restore operation to be slow can be

1. Hardisk where you are restoring is not able to cope up with I/O request which is required to meet all requests. May be its a busy disk whoes I/O is getting utilized by other process and you started a restore creating extra load and more candidated for I/O. May be disk is slow, requiring some firmware upgrade
2. Database which you are restoring had [to many Virtual log files](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/saponsqlserver/too-many-virtual-log-files-vlfs-can-cause-slow-database-recovery) or when backup was taken some process was rolling back. So now when database will recovery it would make sure that process rolls back completely and then only it can make database online. Backup includes both data and some amount of transaction log to bring database in transactionally consistent state. The amount of transaction log included depends on transaction that were running when backup was  happening. To understand backup please read [this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/technet-magazine/dd822915%28v=msdn.10%29)

You must read [Optimizing backup and restore in SQL Server](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/sql/sql-server-2008-r2/ms190954%28v=sql.105%29)

Why copy operation took 30 mins totally depends on load on network and size of backup file being transferred

Comment: The disk is able to cope with loading, about it tells 30 minutes of copying.
With a dump file everything is good. If I restore a backup on the next disk, it will take 30 minutes.
Such problem arises only at restoration on a SSD disk.
All files are located locally, the network isn't used.